# You can't love your country only when you win

Tags: meaning

President Biden said in his State of the Union this year as follows:

"My predecessor and some of you here seek to bury the truth of January 6th.
I will not do that.
This is a moment to speak the truth and bury the lies.
And here’s the simplest truth. You can’t love your country only when you win."

What does he mean by saying "You can't love your country only when you win?"